# Ngrx/data getWithQuery does not filter data according to the query I gave it

Tags: angular-ngrx-data

When I try to query for Approved Tags like so, it returns all entries not the approved ones

```
getAllApprovedTags(): Observable<Array<Tag>> {
    return this.tagsService.getWithQuery({tagStatus:'Approved'});
}
```

I have also tried the following

```
getAllApprovedTags(): Observable<Array<Tag>> {
        return this.tagsService.getWithQuery("tagStatus='Approved'");
}
```

And the following

```
getAllApprovedTags(): Observable<Array<Tag>> {
        return this.tagsService.getWithQuery("tagStatus=Approved");
}
```

I am using

> ```
> Angular CLI: 11.0.1
> Node: 10.19.0
> OS: linux x64
> NgRx/Data: 10.1.2
> ```

The back-end is

> Loopback 4 and MongoDB

I have the following model

```
export class Tag {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public tagName: string,
    public tagDescription: string,
    public tagStatus: string,
    public createdDate: Date,
  ){ }
}
```

My entity config looks like the following

```
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Tag: {},
};

const pluralNames = {
  Tag: 'Tags',
};

export const entityConfig = {
  entityMetadata,
  pluralNames,
};
```

The service class looks like the following

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TagsService  extends EntityCollectionServiceBase <Tag> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super('Tag', serviceElementsFactory);
   }
}
```

The data is as follows

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI0t7.png)

Answer (score 0):

`getWithQuery` simply adds query parameters to the endpoint URL:

```
/api/tags/?tagStatus=Approved
```

Even if the server is set up to handle this, it may not be what you're trying to do. More context is needed, but based off your question, it *sounds* like you're wanting to filter the collection of `Tag` entities down to those whose status is "Approved". If so, maybe you want `filterFn` ([docs here](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata#filterfn)):

```js
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Tag: {
    filterFn: (tags: Tag[], status: TagStatus) => {
      return tags.filter(tag => tag.status === status);
    }
  },
};
```

And in your component:

```js
getAllApprovedTags(): Observable<Array<Tag>> {
  this.tagService.setFilter(TestStatus.Approved); // or 'Approved' if you don't use an enum
  return this.tagsService.filteredEntities$;
}
```

**However**, from my understanding, any other places using that filter would also be changed, so it may be better for your use case to use a `selector`.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TagsService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase <Tag> {

  approvedTags$ = this.entities$.pipe(select(selectApprovedTags));

  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super('Tag', serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

```js
// selectors

export const selectApprovedTags = createSelector(
  (tags) => tags,
  (tags: Tag[]) => tags.filter(tag => tag.status === TagStatus.Approved)
);
```

above `selector` implementation based on what I'm seeing in their [demo](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/data-example-app/src/state/story.selectors.ts)

Comment: Follow the docs at https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice